# error convert onnx to tflite : KeyError: 'input.1'

Tags: converters, onnx, tflite

what should I do to get tflite from onnx
here is my code :

```
!onnx-tf convert -i "/content/drive/MyDrive/model.onnx" -o "/content/model.pb"
```

and my error message is :
x = ag__.ld(input_dict)[ag__.ld(node).inputs[0]]
tensorflow.python.autograph.pyct.error_utils.MultilineMessageKeyError: in user code:

```
File "/content/onnx-tensorflow/onnx_tf/backend_tf_module.py", line 99, in __call__  *
    output_ops = self.backend._onnx_node_to_tensorflow_op(onnx_node,
File "/content/onnx-tensorflow/onnx_tf/backend.py", line 347, in _onnx_node_to_tensorflow_op  *
    return handler.handle(node, tensor_dict=tensor_dict, strict=strict)
File "/content/onnx-tensorflow/onnx_tf/handlers/handler.py", line 59, in handle  *
    return ver_handle(node, **kwargs)
File "/content/onnx-tensorflow/onnx_tf/handlers/backend/conv.py", line 15, in version_11  *
    return cls.conv(node, kwargs["tensor_dict"])
File "/content/onnx-tensorflow/onnx_tf/handlers/backend/conv_mixin.py", line 29, in conv  *
    x = input_dict[node.inputs[0]]

KeyError: 'input.1'
```

I have onnx model, and I want to try convert to tflite (I using google colab)
first code :

```
!git clone https://github.com/onnx/onnx-tensorflow.git
!cd onnx-tensorflow && pip install -e .
```

and its work
and then I write

```
# Convert .onnx model to TensorFlow Freeze Graph
!onnx-tf convert -i "/content/drive/MyDrive/model.onnx" -o "/content/model.pb"
```

and the error messgae appear,
please help me guys